# How to understand Bulk transfer using libusb

Tags: usb, libusb

Say I have an USB device, a camera for instance, and I would like to load the image sequence captured by the camera to the host, using libusb API.

It is not clear to me for the following points:

1. How is the IN Endpoint on the device populated? Is it always the full image data of one frame (and optionally plus some status data)?
2. libusb_bulk_transfer() has a parameter `length` to specify how long is the data the host wants to read IN, and another parameter `transferred` indicating how much data actually had been transferred. The question is: should I always request the same amount of data that the IN Endpoint would send? If so, then what would be the case where `transferred` was smaller than `length`?
3. How is it determined how much data would be sent by the In Endpoint upon each transfer request?

Comment: I think you need to have spec for this USB device (camera). There should be described format of the data you will get from bulk endpoint.